# Replacing *target* characters in RegEx without losing anything

Tags: regex, search, replace, sublimetext3, search-regex

**parameter**

In Sublime Text 3 I am using the following RegEx code as my search combo to find `any alphabet character preceding 0, followed by a space, followed by another character` which is as follows:

**RegEx Code**

```
[a-z]0 [a-z]
```

**Search Target Examples**

```
Eg.1  a0 p
Eg.2  p0 sa
Eg.3  ap0 l
```

**Question**:
What RegEx code should I write so that it replaces all such occurrences containing the 0s with a dot (.) i.e., it should become like this: 
**Replace Objective of Target Examples**

```
Eg.1  a0 p    → a. p
Eg.2  p0 s    → p. sa
Eg.3  ap0 l   → ap. l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html):

Regex: `([a-z])0( [a-z])`
Replacement: `$1.$2`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e38ewI/1)

**Details**:

- `([a-z])` - matches and captures into Group 1 any ASCII lowercase letter
- `0` - a literal `0` is matched
- `( [a-z])` - Group 2: a space and a lowercase ASCII letter

The replacement contains the backreference to the value stored in Group 1 (`$1`), then we replace `0` with a dot, and use the backreference to Group 2 contents (`$2`).

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Comment: I actually did upvoted your post in addition to marking it as an answer. However for some reasons, it did not get upvoted at the first attempted. I have done it again and should work now.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. I got the same issue but this time it's the **॥** char wrapping numbers and they are in italics (in a word document) and in each line, it goes something like that ** ॥ 4 ॥**, **॥ 5 ॥**, **॥ 6 ॥** ... **॥ 36 ॥**, **॥ 37 ॥** etc.  What RegEx code to type to select them and change it from italic to regular.

Comment: @VinayaŚiṣya: Sorry, no idea what you mean. If it is a new question, please post.